# Accessing values from Children Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift3

I am really not quite understanding the updates to the Swift 3.0 Firebase syntax, but most of all retrieving values from children of a snapshot seems to be impossible. To do so, I use a snippet like this:

```
 if let snapVal = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
     for c in snapshot.children {
                        let cx = (c as! AnyObject)
                        let name = cx["NAME"] as! String

     }
}
```

I have taken many approaches to this but FIRDatabaseSnapshot has many restrictions in the new Swift 3 update, and AnyObject does not allow for values to be read from the object and NSDictionary-like types do not have children either. All help is very appreciated, thank you!

Comment: What is snapshot?

Comment: Snapshot is of type FIRDatasnapshot

Answer (score 2):

The snapShot that you receive of type `FIRDataSnapshot` is actually a custom class conforming to **`NSObject`**, so only the variables conforming to `FIRDataSnapshot` can access the custom function that `FIRDataSnapshot` provides such as **`.children`**.

But when you are accessing a new variable whose value is `snap.value` parsed as **[String:AnyObject]**, basically it becomes a NSDictionary, and NSDictionary doesn't has any parameter `.children`.

```
  FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("your_Ref").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snap) in

        for each in snap.children{

            print(each)


        }
      if let snapDict = snap.value as? [String:AnyObject]{

            for each in snapDict{

                let keyID = each.key
                let childValue = each.value["NAME"] as! String
            }
        }

    })
```

Comment: Good catch! I overlooked that conversion in the first line.

Comment: Yes but once I try: `if child.hasChild("NAME"){ }`, it says `Value of type 'NSFastEnumerationIterator.Element' (aka 'Any') has no member 'hasChild'` @FrankvanPuffelen @Dravidian

Comment: It offers the option to convert to type AnyObject, but that causes ambiguity later

Comment: My answer was to merely explain you the underlying concept, For retrieving values - Answer Updated.